# Passport authentication showing unauthorized in node.js after registering the data successfully in my database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have made a register route with a docSchema registration using the register function of the class.
Now the problem is that upon registering on the frontend it does not throw any error but rather registers the data in my database but does not redirect to the login route. Rather, it throws the unauthorized 401 error and my login route shows the same upon logging in with the right details. What's strange is that the exact code was working before without any problem. Please help me with this issue.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


const app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// ----- User Session ------
app.use(session({
    secret: "anthonymnoasisaidp@$gdhdks.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
// --------------------------

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//------- Connecting MongoDB --------
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/Doctors", {useNewUrlParser: true});
const docSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: String,
    qualifications: String,
    exp: String,
    email: String,
    password: String

});

const patSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: String,
    sex: String,
    bpm: Object,
    medicines: Object,
    past_rec: String,
    ecg_analysis: Object

});


patSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

docSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

//--------doctor credentials collection---------------------

const doc = new mongoose.model("doctor_cred", docSchema);
passport.use(doc.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(doc.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(doc.deserializeUser());

//------------------------------------------------------------

//------------patient collection details----------------------

const pat = new mongoose.model("patient_cred", patSchema);
passport.use(pat.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(pat.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(pat.deserializeUser());

//------------------------------------------------------------







// ------Home Route---------

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});

// ------ end ----------------

// ---------- Login Route -----

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
})

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    const user = new doc({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.login(user, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res, function(){
                res.redirect('/doctor-dashboard');
            });
        }
    })
})
//--------end------------------

//------Register Route/ Doctors----------
app.get('/register',function(req,res){
    res.render("register");
})

app.post('/register',function(req,res){

    doc.register({username: req.body.username,name: req.body.name ,age: req.body.age ,qualifications: req.body.qualifications ,exp: req.body.exp}, req.body.password, function(err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res, function(){
                res.redirect("/login");
            });
        }
    })

})
//---------end-------------------------

//------------doctor dashboard---------
app.get('/doctor-dashboard',function(req,res){
    doc.findById(req.user.id)
                .then(function(userfound){
                    if(userfound){
                        const name =userfound.name;
                        const age = userfound.age;
                        const qualifications = userfound.qualifications;
                        const exp = userfound.exp;
                        res.render('docdash', {name: name, age: age, qualifications: qualifications, exp: exp});

                    }

                });
})

//--------------------------------------

//--------------doctor dashboard My Patients Route-----------
// app.get('/doctor-dashboard/My-Patients',function(req,res){
    

// });





app.get("/services",function(req,res){
    res.render("services");
});

app.listen("5000",function(){
    console.log("listening on port 5000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    name: String,
    age: String,
    qualifications: String,
    exp: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
------------
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age,
        qualifications: req.body.qualifications,
        exp: req.body.exp
    });

    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
                res.redirect("/login");
            });
        }
    });
});
 combine both
```